# What exactly should the crash report I send to sentry, look like?

Tags: java, android, sdk, sentry

I'm new to a team that's building an android sdk, and we're using sentry to report crashes. I have to update our code relating to sentry because apparently we're not doing it right, since the crash reports we get in sentry can't be filtered correctly. I have read sentry documentations, and I see examples of json objects that are sent to the sentry server, but they're less complicated than what I'm currently working with. From the documentations I understand that I should do the crash reporting differently for a sdk (comparing to an appliation). I would appreciate some guidance or resources on where to go from here.

So this is where I report the crash:

```
public static void sendCrashReport(Context context, Throwable throwable) {  //todo make cache request
        ApiClient client = ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiClient.class);
        Call<Void> call = client.crashReport(
                "https://sentrypackage/api/<project_id>/store/",
                "Sentry sentry_version=6,sentry_client=sentry-java/version,sentry_key=mykey",
                CrashReporting.makeReport(context, throwable));

        call.enqueue(defaultCallback);
    }
```

```
    @POST()
    Call<Void> crashReport(
            @Url() String url,
            @Header("X-Sentry-Auth") String sentryToken,
            @Body SentryCrashModel body);
```

and CrashReporting.makeReport methods, makes the complex nested json object, which looks like something like this:

```
public class SentryCrashModel {

    @SerializedName("message")
    public String message;

    @SerializedName("timestamp")
    public String timestamp;

    @SerializedName("platform")
    public String platform;

    @SerializedName("contexts")
    public ContextModel contexts;

    @SerializedName("tags")
    public TagsModel tags;

    @SerializedName("sentry.interfaces.Exception")
    public ExeptionModel crashElement;

    @SerializedName("sentry.interfaces.User")
    public UserModel user;
}
```

So I want to know how exactly should I send the crash to sentry and what is the exact structure of it, and I want to know if I'm doing it wrong or not. I'm not getting any errors in my IDE when I test my sdk, but I can't filter my report in sentry correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sentry build SDKs for all major languages and frameworks.
There's an SDK for Android, the documentation is here:

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/android/

You can create a new project in Sentry, select platform Android and the wizard tells you steps to get it up. Same steps are on the docs link above.

In a nutshell, add the SDK to your app's gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:3.0.0'
}
```

Then add the Sentry DSN (the URL that tells where Sentry's SDK should send the event to):

For example (**MAKE SURE TO ADD YOUR OWN DSN**, get it on sentry.io when you create a project or in the project settings "Client Keys"):

Add this to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<application>
  <meta-data android:name="io.sentry.dsn" android:value="__DSN__" />
</application>
```

That's all you need to do to capture ANRs, Uncaught Exceptions, native (C/C++) crashes from NDK, and track [the health of your releases](https://docs.sentry.io/product/releases/health/).

The SDK offers an API you can use to add more data to the events sent to Sentry, filter things out and capture some custom messages or Exceptions through `try catch` for example. Check the docs for that.

You then probably want to configure `proguard` if you're using that. More details in the docs.